# pythonで3次元配列を2次元配列に変換したい

Tags: python

pythonで3次元配列を2次元配列に変換したい。

```
li=[[[1,2],[2,5,8]],[[1,5,9],[9,10,11],[11,13]],[[2,6,12],[12,17,15],[15,3,2]]]    

li=[[1,2,5,8],[1,5,9,10,11,13],[2,6,12,17,15,3,2]]
```

上記の例のように変換したいです。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: `[[1,2],[2,5,8]]` が `[1,2,5,8]` になっていますが、`[1,2,2,5,8]` ではないのですね？

Comment: 元々、リストの末尾と次のリストの先頭が同じというのが前提なのでは？そして、その部分でリストをつなげるということが、この質問の意図ではないのでしょうか？

Comment: 変換の仕様が不明確です。他の方が推測してるとおり、リストの末尾とその次の先頭は必ず一緒という前提なのか、それともそうでない特別なルールがあるのか分かりません。

Comment: 末尾を削らなくていいなら`print [sum(l, []) for l in li]`とするだけなんですけどね(^^;;;

Comment: 誰かreduceとmapとlambdaで作れないかなぁ。リストコンプリヘンションも除外して、関数ちっくに解いてみたい。

Answer (score 2):

`li[i][j][-1]` と `li[i][j+1][0]` が同じ値、という前提が成り立つ場合。

```
>>> [sum([y[:-1] for y in x[:-1]], []) + x[-1] for x in li]
[[1, 2, 5, 8], [1, 5, 9, 10, 11, 13], [2, 6, 12, 17, 15, 3, 2]]
```

もしくは、

```
>>> [x[0] + sum([y[1:] for y in x[1:]], []) for x in li]
[[1, 2, 5, 8], [1, 5, 9, 10, 11, 13], [2, 6, 12, 17, 15, 3, 2]]
```

※ Kenji Noguchi さんのコメントから

> ならば `print [sum([y[1:] for y in x[1:]], x[0]) for x in li]` これが一番シンプルかも。

Comment: なるほど〜。ならば`print [sum([y[1:] for y in x[1:]], x[0]) for x in li]`これが一番シンプルかも。リストコンプリヘンションのネストは御法度かもしれませんが。

Comment: あ、x[0] を sum の第2引数にすれば良いのですね。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1):

データ通りに実装するとこのようになります。

```
>>> li=[[[1,2],[2,5,8]],[[1,5,9],[9,10,11],[11,13]],[[2,6,12],[12,17,15],[15,3,2]]]    
>>> result = []
>>> for x in li:
...     r = []
...     for y in x:
...         if r and r[-1] == y[0]:
...             r.extend(y[1:])
...         else:
...             r.extend(y)
...     result.append(r)
...
>>> result
[[1, 2, 5, 8], [1, 5, 9, 10, 11, 13], [2, 6, 12, 17, 15, 3, 2]]
```

Answer (score 0):

forループ無しで解いてみました。

```
li=[[[1,2],[2,5,8]],[[1,5,9],[9,10,11],[11,13]],[[2,6,12],[12,17,15],[15,3,2]]]
print map(lambda e: reduce(lambda a, b: a + b[1:], e), li)
```